# FileNotFoundException although file exists

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin.mac

My program's throwing a FileNotFoundException, although the file is definitely there.

I'm currently working on an application that used plugins. In the plugin directory, there is a file "plugins.include", where one can list locations of dlls to be included.

When I load the DLLs directly from the folder, everything works fine.
However, if I add the path

```
/Users/simoncahill/Projects/MailArchive/TestPlugin/bin/TestPlugin.dll
```

it can't find the file, although it definitely exists:

[image: File Location]

Has anyone else experienced this sort of issue? 
What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: As pointed out to me, I missed a folder in the path, while copying from the Finder.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `Debug` folder after `bin` folder:

```
/Users/simoncahill/Projects/MailArchive/TestPlugin/bin/Debug/TestPlugin.dll
```